# Replace Custom Element with template itself (rather than including it inside the custom element) in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Let's say I have a custom element `<foo-bar></foo-bar>`
Rather than render the markup into the tags, I want to replace them so that the "foo-bar" element is no longer part of the DOM. I believe Angular does this via the transclude property.

Is there a way to do this in Aurelia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `containerless` decorator on your component.

From the documentation's [Custom Elements Section](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.5/doc/article/cheat-sheet):

> `@containerless()` - Causes the element's view to be rendered without the custom element container wrapping it. This cannot be used in conjunction with `@sync` or `@useShadowDOM`. It also cannot be uses with surrogate behaviors.

So your component should look like this:

```
import {customElement, bindable, containerless} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('say-hello')
@containerless()
export class SayHello {
  @bindable to;

  speak(){
    alert(`Hello ${this.to}!`);
  }
}
```